# Java - Как изменить заднюю полоску seekbar?

Tags: java, android

Как изменить цвет задней части в seekbar?
https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LKOrej6RVkM/VpjAx28xDGI/AAAAAAAAcNo/_CZsFf725cw/s1600/AndroidSeekBarDrawable2.png - то, что красным цветом.

Comment: Куча инфы. Вот например http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/11/android-custom-seekbar-example.html?m=1

Comment: Спасибо, не знаю, просто как называется эта часть в нём, уже нашёл.